# VBA searching for value then convert it to =weeknum

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do the following;

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SReph.png)

It should work as following;

- The code searches all of column A for a date (starting at A3)
- If there is a date, then it would convert it to a week number in (Starting B3) column B
- If there isn't a date found, then it should leave the cell empty

This is what I have so far:

```
For i = 1 To qColumns
    If Range(oColNameE & 3, oColNameE & qRows).Value = vbNullString Then
        Range(oColNameF & 3, oColNameF & qRows).Value = ""
    Else: Range(oColNameF & 2, oColNameF & qRows).Value = "=weeknum"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `Else: Range(oColNameF & 2, oColNameF & qRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=YourWeekNumCalcFormula"`

Comment: I put it there, but then i get runtime error 13. Type missmatch. on second line of code

Comment: record macro while entering Week Number formula into the cell. Later user that code as formula for that line... or as example it will look similar to the below code:

`Dim WeekNum as String

WeekNum = "=Round(((RC[-1]*RC[-3])/10)+(RC[-5]*1.25),2)"` place it before Loop, later
`Else: Range(oColNameF & 2, oColNameF & qRows).FormulaR1C1  =WeekNum `

Comment: Can't you just use =iferror(weeknum(a3), "")?  A formula, not vba.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, my comment looks difficult to read.

```
Dim weeknum as String

weeknum = "=WEEKNUM(RC[-1]-95,11)"

For i = 1 To qCollumns
If Range(oColNameE & 3, oColNameE & qRows).Value = vbNullString Then
    Range(oColNameF & 3, oColNameF & qRows).Value = ""
        Else: Range(oColNameF & 2, oColNameF & qRows).FormulaR1C1 = weeknum 
        End If
Next
```